Robot_localization dual-ekf + navsat problem - jumps, high drift and wrong movements in odom_frame
I'm trying to use the 3-nodes setup of ekf_odom, ekf_map and navsat_transform for uav with ArduCopter.
I'm working in ros2 humble, ubuntu 22.04 in Gazebo Classic 11 simulation.
The nodes are in 3d mode and I fuse:

Imu data (lin_acc + angulat_vel + orientation) from mavros imu plugin
Z pose from barometer
(x,y) velocities from optical flow with camera heading down.
GPS x,y pose from mavros.

an example for every message is shared down there :)
Im fusing the same sensors data to the map&odom ekf nodes, with the addition of /odometry/gps from the navsat_transform which is fused into the map_ekf.
The main problems I have:

when running odom_ekf_node solo - even when the vehicle is not moving at all (in the beginning), I see very accurate data in odom frame (because of the 0 velocity in x,y), but when the map_ekf_node is running too - the data gets drifted very hard from the center in map frame.
when I'm in flight, and I rotate in the yaw axis (z angular velocity) - the base_link (odom_ekf output) is doing circles around the odom frame in the xy plane, even though there is no data that says it to it (the imu & optical_flow msgs from the rotation is also attached below).

Bonus, just if you feel generous - In general, I have some beliefs that I want to check with you:

I fuse any measurement that I fuse in the odom frame ekf also to the map frame ekf, because the 2 ekfs have no connection (so i want to help both of them). is it ok?
is there any case to use the local ekf output in the global map? or should i just use the global output in map_frame for navigation and local output in the odom_frame for obstacle avoidance?
with this set of sensors - do you think I need the 2 sets of ekf? does it harm me to do the dual-ekf configuration just in case i'll need some local-navigation?

Thank you all!
Attachments:

config yaml file:

        ### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node_odom:
        ros__parameters:
                use_sim_time: true         
                frequency: 9.0             
                # sensor_timeout: 0.1
                two_d_mode: false

                transform_time_offset: 0.0

                transform_timeout: 0.0

                print_diagnostics: true
                debug: false

                debug_out_file: /workspaces/apm_ws/logs/ekf_log.txt

                permit_corrected_publication: false

                publish_acceleration: false

                publish_tf: true

                reset_on_time_jump: true


                map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
                odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
                base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
                world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

                # initial_state: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
                pose0: /ekf_wrapper/hdg_and_alt
                pose0_config: [false,  false,  true,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]
                pose0_differential: false
                pose0_relative: false
                pose0_queue_size: 50

                twist0: /optical_flow/twist_with_cov
                twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                true,  true,  false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]
                twist0_queue_size: 15

                imu0: /mavros/imu/data
                imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                                true, true, true,
                                false, false, false,
                                true, true, true,
                                true, true, true]

                imu0_nodelay: false
                imu0_differential: false
                imu0_relative: false
                imu0_queue_size: 100
                imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

          
                process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
                                          
           
                initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]


ekf_filter_node_map:
        ros__parameters:
                use_sim_time: true
                frequency: 9.0
                two_d_mode: false
                transform_time_offset: 0.0
                transform_timeout: 0.0
                print_diagnostics: true
                debug: true
                debug_out_file: /workspaces/apm_ws/logs/ekf_log.txt

                permit_corrected_publication: false

                publish_acceleration: false

                publish_tf: true

                reset_on_time_jump: true


                map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
                odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
                base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
                world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

                # initial_state: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                #                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
                pose0: /ekf_wrapper/hdg_and_alt
                pose0_config: [false,  false,  true,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]
                pose0_differential: false
                pose0_relative: false
                pose0_queue_size: 50

                twist0: /optical_flow/twist_with_cov
                twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                true,  true,  false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]
                twist0_queue_size: 15

                imu0: /mavros/imu/data
                imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                                true, true, true,
                                false, false, false,
                                true, true, true,
                                true, true, true]
                imu0_nodelay: false
                imu0_differential: false
                imu0_relative: false
                imu0_queue_size: 100
              
                imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

                odom0: /odometry/gps
                odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false,
                                false, false, false]
                odom0_queue_size: 100
                odom0_nodelay: false
                odom0_differential: false
                odom0_relative: false
         
                process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
                                             
              
                dynamic_process_noise_covariance: false
                initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]

navsat_transform:
        ros__parameters:
                use_sim_time: true
                frequency: 1.0
                delay: 7.0
                magnetic_declination_radians: 0.090408055  # For lat/long of 32 34
                yaw_offset: 0.0  # if IMU reads 0 when facing magnetic north instead of east then set parameter to pi/2
                zero_altitude: false
                broadcast_cartesian_transform: true
                broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false
                publish_filtered_gps: true
                use_odometry_yaw: false
                datum: [32.22,34.92,61.33]
                wait_for_datum: true




Launch file:

<launch>
    <node name="ekf_wrapper" exec="ekf_wrapper" pkg="mav_drone_localization" args="--ros-args --log-level warn"/>

    <node pkg="robot_localization" exec="ekf_node" name="ekf_filter_node_odom">
        <param from="$(find-pkg-share mav_drone_localization)/config/ekf_mav_with_gps.yaml"/>
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/local"/>
</node>
<node pkg="robot_localization" exec="ekf_node" name="ekf_filter_node_map">
    <param from="$(find-pkg-share mav_drone_localization)/config/ekf_mav_with_gps.yaml"/>
        <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/global"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="robot_localization" exec="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform">
        <param from="$(find-pkg-share mav_drone_localization)/config/ekf_mav_with_gps.yaml"/>
        <remap from="/imu/data" to="/mavros/imu/data" />
        <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/mavros/global_position/raw/fix" />
        <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/global" /> 
        <remap from="/datum" to="/navsat_transform/set_datum" /> 
    </node>
</launch>


Imu msg (not moving):

header:
  stamp:
    sec: 2998
    nanosec: 511000000
  frame_id: base_link
orientation:
  x: 0.0002997842660943451
  y: 8.160078365943124e-07
  z: -0.8841530849517731
  w: -0.4671972094297979
orientation_covariance:
- 2.5e-07
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 2.5e-07
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 2.5e-07
angular_velocity:
  x: -0.0009947237558662891
  y: -0.004728054162114858
  z: 0.0060912524349987516
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 1.2184700254281e-07
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.2184700254281e-07
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.2184700254281e-07
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.0
  y: 1.202169221539125e-15
  z: 9.81645665
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0


/ekf_wrapper/hdg_and_alt (only for z pose):

header:
  stamp:
    sec: 361
    nanosec: 379000000
  frame_id: odom
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.24277789388709436
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: -0.0
      z: -0.7080933989149113
      w: -0.7061187849173313
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.10452549516925765
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.02
---


/odometry/gps:

  stamp:
    sec: 399
    nanosec: 610000000
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: ''
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.6099999999999994
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance:
  - 0.09000000000000001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.09000000000000001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.09
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
---



/optical_flow/twist_with_cov - not moving:

  stamp:
    sec: 429
    nanosec: 418000000
  frame_id: odom
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 50.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 50.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
---



/optical_flow/twist_with_cov - rotating (z) in place - which causes circles around odom origin

  stamp:
    sec: 2658
    nanosec: 76000000
  frame_id: odom
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.04082316095207475
      y: -0.09747442370915278
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.26225962721734064
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.056506090246433556
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
---


images:
Rviz2 snapshot of all the odometry msgs of the system. this is the beginning of the drift.


The short answer is that the ROS2 ecosystem currently does not have a high performance, actively maintained, versatile, and fully documented solution for fusing IMU, GPS, and MAG. robot_localization is in a vague, partially deprecated state, and fuse, one possible replacement, lacks working code and tutorials that would allow non-specialists to build a reliable/working solution rapidly (e.g. within a month or two). A contributing factor is that fusing IMU, GPS, and MAG is inherently very difficult, since it needs to deal with time synchronization/lags of multiple data streams, details of the drone/robot (inertia, which axes are bring controlled, 2D vs. 3D), and calibration of the various sensors (hard and soft iron of the MAG which also varies with angles/current to servos).
For other ecosystems, such as Ardupilot, fusing IMU, GPS, and MAG is arguably one of central functions of the software (aside from basic platform stability / flight control) and thus, the level of time and effort that is spent making sure that all works, is vastly different and therefore a typical Ardupilot user will be able to calibrate their drone/UAV within an hour or two. This is not the case with ROS2.
One specific answer - the issue with your "is doing circles around the odom frame in the xy plane" is that you are not providing data, for whatever reason, that constrains the yaw. This is what happens when (1) the yaw sensor goes offline, or (2) you have not provided a suitable yaw signal input. And then, since there are no data, the unconstrained axis just spins.
